# Registering an Angular ErrorHandler?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, stackblitz

Tried registering an Angular `ErrorHandler` in [this minimal stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nervous-system-brain?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts), however it is not logging the error that is thrown in the constructor of the `HelloComponent`.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you please add your code to the question?

Comment: The stackblitz is super minimal.  It only contains the error handler and the corresponding providers configuration in the app module.

Comment: Yeah it's still good to post the code in the question in case the link stops working at some point in the future. Even better if it's super minimal

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on how to register a handler.  It's just that it's not working for me.  Lets keep the noise in the question to a minimum until we figure out what the relevant details are.

Comment: See - The issue had to do with stackblitz - nothing to do with the code.  If anyone wants to know how to perform ErrorHandling registration they can just google that.  Adding unnecessary details just wastes the readers time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is that by `throw`ing the `Error` in the `constructor` of `HelloComponent`, you're not really allowing the `ErrorHandler` to get registered.

If you throw the Error after the Application has bootstrapped properly, probably on a click of a button, then your ErrorHandler should catch it.

Try this in your AppComponent Template:

```
...

<button (click)="throwError()">Click Me To Generate Error</button>
```

And in your AppComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent  {
  ...
  throwError() {
    throw new Error("This error should be caught by our handler.");
  }
}
```

And your HelloComponent:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nervous-system-brain-qte3xc?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

[image]

Comment: I tried clicking the button, but I don't see the `console.log('The error is',  error);` triggered in the error handler.  Thoughts?

Comment: I tried opening the dev tools / browser console and I still don't see `The error is: ...` being invoked.  Do you see it?

Comment: You probably misread my comment above. I specified that you'll have to **Open In New Window** and then click on the button to see the message on the console. Right now you're seeing it on the console of StackBlitz only. That's why you're seeing message: **Error: Object too large to inspect. Open your browser console to view.**